# Compare two different columns from two different tables and show other column's data from either table using orm relationship in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, orm

I have two models one is **Companies** and another one is **Interviews**.
The **Companies** table primary key is *Company_details_id* and this key is used as a foreign key *f_company_id* in Interviews table.

Now my question was how to compare both key values if my condition is true it will return the column *company_name* from **companies** table.

My Companies model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Companies extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'company_details';

  protected $primaryKey = 'company_details_id';


  public function interviews()
  {
      return $this->hasmany('App\Interviews', 'f_company_id');
  }


}
```

My Interviews model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Interviews extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'interview_schedule';

 protected $primaryKey ='schedule_id';



 public function getCompanies()  
   {
        return $this->belongsto('App/Companies'); 
    }


}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Companies;
use App\Interviews;


class PracticeController extends Controller

{
   public function getAll()
   {

    $getcompany=Companies::where('Companies.company_details_id','=','Interviews.f_company_id')
                 ->select('company_name')->get();

      echo $getcompany; 

   }


}
```

please, guys, I need a clear answer using with eloquent orm in laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but here's a few guidelines.

Firstly you appear to have "one company can have many interviews" and "an interview can only belong to one company" as your relationships. You have set these up correctly in your models for the most part.

Because of your relationship, your "getAll" query should simply be:

```
$companies = Company::with(['interviews'])->select(['company_name'])->get();
```

Then you can just loop through them with relative ease:

```
foreach($companies as $company)
{
  foreach($company->interviews as $interview) {
    // Do something with $interview
  }
}
```

Using *with* calls the relationship "interviews" which performing all of the where clauses between the two tables naturally, based on assumed keys. As you appear to have non-standard primary keys, you'll need to define the hasMany and belongsTo in more detail.

```
public function interviews()
{ 
  return $this->hasMany(Interview::class, 'f_company_id', 'company_details_id');
}
```

I recommend calling your models Company and Interview, not the plural versions. This is because a single record deals with a single company (an assumption based on what you wrote). You'll find it less confusing in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
 DB::table('interview_schedule')
 ->select('company.company_name')
 ->join('company','company_details.company_details_id','=','interview_schedule.f_company_id')
 ->where('interview_schedule.f_company_id','=','company.company_details_id')
 ->get();
```

Hope this work for you!